# Alternative to deeply nested promises

Tags: javascript

There is a series of operations related to cryptography that I would prefer to serialize. However that does not seem to be possible at all in javascript. Here is the result using `Promises`.

```
importKey(pemPriv).then(impPrivKey=> {
    console.log(`impPrivKey: ${impPrivKey}`)
    importKey(pemPub,'encrypt').then(impPubKey=> {
        importKey(pemPriv,'decrypt').then(impPrivKey=> {
            console.log(`impPubKey: ${impPubKey}`)
            encrypt(impPubKey  , "hello world!").then(enc => {
                console.log(`encrypted: ${enc}`)
                decrypt(impPrivKey, enc).then(dec => {
                    console.log(`decrypted: ${dec}`)
                })
            })
        })
    })
})
```

This is unwieldy: is there any alternative to handling sequential `Promises` that avoids the progressive nesting?

Comment: *Continuation Passing Style* is one such alternative.

Comment: thx - I'm looking at that now.

Comment: Eh.  It looks like you're already doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Async/Await as long as you run it in an asynchronous function.

```
const encryptDecrypt = async (pemPriv) => {

  const impPrivKey = await importKey(pemPriv);
  console.log(`impPrivKey: ${impPrivKey}`);
  const impPubKey = await importKey(pemPub,'encrypt');
  const impPrivKey = await importKey(pemPriv,'decrypt');
  console.log(`impPubKey: ${impPubKey}`);
  const enc = await encrypt(impPubKey  , "hello world!");
  console.log(`encrypted: ${enc}`);
  const dec = await decrypt(impPrivKey, enc);
  console.log(`decrypted: ${dec}`);

}

encryptDecrypt(pemPriv);
```

Comment: Yes I think this is what I were after.  The nesting was getting awkward.

Answer (score 3):

Promise chaining is what you want, any `.then` handler that returns a Promise can be chained, but since you also need access to each result along the way you'll need to use a closure to store the intermediate results, like this:

```
function decrypt() { 
    const pemPriv = // some private key
    const pemPub = // some public key

    const privateKey;
    const publicKey;

    importKey(pemPriv)
        .then(impPrivKey => {
            console.log(`impPrivKey: ${impPrivKey}`)
            privateKey = impPrivKey;
            return importKey(pemPub, 'encrypt');
        })
        .then(impPubKey => {
            console.log(`impPubKey: ${impPubKey}`)
            publicKey = impPubKey // Optional
            return encrypt(publicKey, "hello world!")
        })
        .then(enc => {
            console.log(`encrypted: ${enc}`)
            return decrypt(privateKey, enc)
        })
        .then(dec => {
            console.log(`decrypted: ${dec}`)
        })
}

decrypt()
```

Comment: This appears to be essentially the same as in the question? Is there a structural change?

Comment: Note how each `.then` is finishing with a return, this allows you to move the next `.then` one level up, the difference is both formatting but also removes a bunch of nesting, allowing you to decouple each handler a bit more. The challenge in your code is that the next handler needs values from not only the previous handler but one before that as well so we need some way to track those.

Comment: oh I see you added placeholders for the intermediate results.  I'm going to upvote this as a useful option - but will retain the linear async method by @James as the most direct answer.

Comment: Totally fair, this answer is useful if one doesn't have access to async/await or simply wants to learn more about how to use Promises

Comment: Totally great reading as well for those that want to know more https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html